# AND statement in Date Range Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form, with a data sheet subform. This subform has rows with WageDate and TipDate. I have the follwing bit of code to filter the the records to display the records with the WageDate that falls in the range:

```
Private Sub btnDateRange_Click()
Dim Filter As String

Filter = "[WageDate] Between #" & Format(Me!TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

Me!sbfrm_qryDeliveries.Form.Filter = Filter
Me!sbfrm_qryDeliveries.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

My question is how do I change this up so that it also filters the TipDate at the same time, so that the resulting records would be those with both WageDate AND TipDate that fall in the selected range? the records might not be equal.  That is, one record may have a WageDate that falls out of the range, but a TipDate that does.

And once I get that figured out, is there a way to selectively SUM a column based on that date?  For instance.  Let's say I filter a date range and four records are returned two have WageDates that fall in the criteria, and two have TipDates thats fall in the criteria.  WageDate and TipDate are both in the same datasheet.  So if I were to just do a SUM of Wage and TipAmount columns I'd get a sum which would include numbers in those columns that don't really belong. The TipAmount column might have an amount come up because the WageDate fell in the range but not the TipDate.  So I need to be able to SUM just the rows in each of those columns that ONLY fall within the selected date range.  I hope this wasn't too confusing.  Maybe there's a better way to do this completely than the way I have it, I don't know.  Oh, for information, the subform is based from a query, and both wages and tips are in their own separate tables. tblWages, tblTips

Comment: Can do conditional expression for a field sum: `Sum(IIf(criteria here, [column], Null))`. But should not need that if recordset filters properly. If you want both fields within given date range, then repeat the BETWEEN AND for the other field. Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Comment: Cross post https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/need-help-with-and-statement-in-date-range-filter-and-sum-specific-records.312009/

Answer (score 0):

> the resulting records would be those with both WageDate AND TipDate
>   that fall in the selected range?

```vb
Private Sub btnDateRange_Click()

    Dim Filter As String

    Filter = "([WageDate] Between #" & Format(Me!TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) " & _
        "And ([TipDate] Between #" & Format(Me!TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"

    Me!sbfrm_qryDeliveries.Form.Filter = Filter
    Me!sbfrm_qryDeliveries.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

However, though not clear, you probably mean OR here:

> one record may have a WageDate that falls out of the range, but a
>   TipDate that does.

```
Filter = "([WageDate] Between #" & Format(Me!TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) " & _
    "Or ([TipDate] Between #" & Format(Me!TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

Note:

> You only need to Format data you plan on displaying.

This is a plain wrong statement. You must format a date value as a *string expression* to concatenate it with the SQL command. If you don't, an implicit cast will be forced on you using whatever the local settings might be, and you loose control. Applying CDate or DateValue doesn't change that and will here be superfluous or even a source of error as they don't accept *Null* values.